# Send SMS with Twilio in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, twilio

I try to use Twilio as an service provider but they have no examples for Swift that I understand.

My task is to send SMS to a number using Twilio API with Swift.

I have a Twilio.com account - and that one is working. But how do I do this in Swift code in a easy manner.

Twilio does provide a library - but that is meant for C# not for Swift (and using a bridging header seems too complicated!)

Here is the C# example, I need a easy Swift example.

```
// Download the twilio-csharp library from twilio.com/docs/csharp/install
using System;
using Twilio;
class Example 
{
  static void Main(string[] args) 
  {
    // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account
    string AccountSid = "AC5ef8732a3c49700934481addd5ce1659";
    string AuthToken = "{{ auth_token }}";
    var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);


    var message = twilio.SendMessage("+14158141829", "+15558675309", "Jenny please?! I love you <3", new string[] {"http://www.example.com/hearts.png"});

    Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Twilio evangelist here.

To send a text message from Swift you can just make a request directly to Twilios REST API.  That said, I **would not** recommend doing this from an iOS app (or any other client app) as it requires you to embed your Twilio account credentials in the app, which is dangerous.  I would instead recommend sending the SMS from a server side application.

If you do want to send the message from your app, there are a couple of Swift libraries I know of that simplify making HTTP requests:

- [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) - from Mattt Thompson, creator of AFNetworking - used in the example here: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/11/how-to-send-an-sms-from-ios-in-swift.html
- [SwiftRequest](https://github.com/rickyrobinett/SwiftRequest) - from Ricky Robinett of Twilio

To make the request using SwiftRequest, it would look like this:

```
var swiftRequest = SwiftRequest();

var data = [
    "To" : "+15555555555",
    "From" : "+15555556666",
    "Body" : "Hello World"
];

swiftRequest.post("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/[YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID]/Messages", 
    auth: ["username" : "[YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID]", "password" : "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN"]
    data: data, 
    callback: {err, response, body in
        if err == nil {
            println("Success: \(response)")
        } else {
            println("Error: \(err)")
        }
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Evangelist Devin :-) Thank you for your answer. I wil consider using server side application, but try this first to se that everything is working as it should.

Comment: would you please guild me .. how can I use **auth: ["username" : "[YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID]", "password" : "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN"]** in Swift NSMutableURLRequest with POST

Comment: Hi Devin, Im using the SwiftRequest as you shown above. I have given my plivo sms API trial credentials and corresponding plivo API url. But I'm getting status code: 401. Could you please tell me what could be the reason. It really helps

Comment: Hi any one tell me how to check user is online or offline ?

Answer (score 5):

recently I have gone through Twilio docs and few SO post.

> **you can send SMS with following code snip in Swift 2.0**

```
func sendSMS()
    {

        let twilioSID = "your Sender ID here"
        let twilioSecret = "your token id here"

        //Note replace + = %2B , for To and From phone number
        let fromNumber = "%2B14806794445"// actual number is +14803606445
        let toNumber = "%2B919152346132"// actual number is +919152346132
        let message = "Your verification code is 2212 for signup with <app name here> "

        // Build the request
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"https://\(twilioSID):\(twilioSecret)@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/\(twilioSID)/SMS/Messages")!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = "From=\(fromNumber)&To=\(toNumber)&Body=\(message)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        // Build the completion block and send the request
        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            print("Finished")
            if let data = data, responseDetails = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                // Success
                print("Response: \(responseDetails)")
            } else {
                // Failure
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }).resume()
}
```

if everything goes fine..You should receive message like this..

[image]

Comment: I am Getting this response. The From phone number +254.... is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account. I am Using Trial Account. Can You please suggest what to do?

Comment: Hi any one tell me how to check user is online or offline ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new Swift example for Passwordless authentication. For the complete tutorial, [Click Here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/03/passwordless-sms-authentication-part-2-building-ios-front-end-with-swift.html)

```
let url = "http://localhost:8000"
  var swiftRequest = SwiftRequest()
  var params:[String:String] = [
    "token" : token!.text
  ]

  swiftRequest.post(url + "/user/auth/", data: params, callback: {err, response, body in
    if( err == nil && response!.statusCode == 200) {
      if((body as NSDictionary)["success"] as Int == 1) {
        self.showAlert("User successfully authenticated!");
      } else {
        self.showAlert("That token isn't valid");
      }
    } else {
      self.showAlert("We're sorry, something went wrong");
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

If You are using server side Swift with Perfect.org 
See this Blog 
http://perfecttwilio.blogspot.in

Answer (score 0):

The answer by "Devin Rader" is perfect. For any other users like me, the following is the full converted code for SwiftRequest for swift 3.0. The original code is by Ricky Robinett.

Please let us know if any errors.

Thankx..

```
//
//  SwiftRequest.swift
//  SwiftRequestTest
//
//  Created by Ricky Robinett on 6/20/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Ricky Robinett. All rights reserved.
//
// ***********************************************************
//
// Modification for Swift 3.0 by Sanjay Sampat on 21.Jun.2017
//
// ***********************************************************

import Foundation

public class SwiftRequest {
    var session = URLSession.shared

    public init() {
        // we should probably be preparing something here...
    }

    // GET requests
    public func get(url: String, auth: [String: String] = [String: String](), params: [String: String] = [String: String](), callback: ((_ err: NSError?, _ response: HTTPURLResponse?, _ body: AnyObject?)->())? = nil) {
        let qs = dictToQueryString(data: params)
        request(options: ["url" : url, "auth" : auth, "querystring": qs ], callback: callback )
    }

    // POST requests
    public func post(url: String, data: [String: String] = [String: String](), auth: [String: String] = [String: String](), callback: ((_ err: NSError?, _ response: HTTPURLResponse?, _ body: AnyObject?)->())? = nil) {
        let qs = dictToQueryString(data: data)
        request(options: ["url": url, "method" : "POST", "body" : qs, "auth" : auth] , callback: callback)
    }

    // Actually make the request
    func request(options: [String: Any], callback: ((_ err: NSError?, _ response: HTTPURLResponse?, _ body: AnyObject?)->())?) {
        if( options["url"] == nil ) { return }

        var urlString = options["url"] as! String
        if( options["querystring"] != nil && (options["querystring"] as! String) != "" ) {
            let qs = options["querystring"] as! String
            urlString = "\(urlString)?\(qs)"
        }

        let url = NSURL(string:urlString)
        let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)

        if( options["method"] != nil) {
            urlRequest.httpMethod = options["method"] as! String
        }

        if( options["body"] != nil && options["body"] as! String != "" ) {
            var postData = (options["body"] as! String).data(using: String.Encoding.ascii, allowLossyConversion: true)
            urlRequest.httpBody = postData
            urlRequest.setValue("\(postData!.count)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-length")
        }

        // is there a more efficient way to do this?
        if( options["auth"] != nil && (options["auth"] as! [String: String]).count > 0) {
            var auth = options["auth"] as! [String: String]
            if( auth["username"] != nil && auth["password"] != nil ) {
                let username = auth["username"]
                let password = auth["password"]
                var authorization = "\(username!):\(password!)"
                if let data = authorization.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                    //authorization = "Basic " + data.base64EncodedString(options: [])
                    authorization = "Basic " + data.base64EncodedString()
                }

                urlRequest.setValue(authorization, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            }
        }

        let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest, completionHandler: {body, response, err in
            let resp = response as! HTTPURLResponse?

            if( err == nil) {
                if let gotResponse = response {
                if(gotResponse.mimeType == "text/html") {
                    let bodyStr = NSString(data: body!, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                    return callback!(err as NSError?, resp, bodyStr)
                } else if(gotResponse.mimeType == "application/xml") {
                    let bodyStr = NSString(data: body!, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                    return callback!(err as NSError?, resp, bodyStr)
                } else if(gotResponse.mimeType == "application/json") {
                    // ss pending
                    do {
                        let jsonAnyObject:AnyObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: (body! as NSData) as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject] as AnyObject
                        return callback!(err as NSError?, resp, jsonAnyObject as AnyObject);
                    } catch _ {
                    }
                }
            }
            }

            return callback!(err as NSError?, resp, body as AnyObject)
        })

        task.resume()
    }

    func request(url: String, callback: ((_ err: NSError?, _ response: HTTPURLResponse?, _ body: AnyObject?)->())? = nil) {
        request(options: ["url" : url ], callback: callback )
    }

    private func dictToQueryString(data: [String: String]) -> String {

        var qs = ""
        for (key, value) in data {
            let encodedKey = encode(value: key)
            let encodedValue = encode(value: value)
            qs += "\(encodedKey)=\(encodedValue)&"
        }
        return qs
    }

    private func encode(value: String) -> String {

        let queryCharacters =  NSCharacterSet(charactersIn:" =\"#%/<>?@\\^`{}[]|&+").inverted

        if let encodedValue:String = value.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: queryCharacters) {
            return encodedValue
        }

        //let encodedValue:String = value.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(queryCharacters)!

        return value
    }
}
```

Sample code to use above class as mentioned by "Devin Rader"

```
    let URL = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/\(myUserIdForBulkSmsMessageSending)/Messages"         
    var swiftRequest = SwiftRequest();

    var data = [
        "To" : "+\(replaceNumberToSendSms)",
        "From" : "+\(replaceNumberFromSendSms)",
        "Body" : message,
        "MediaUrl" : theUrlEncodedMessage
    ];
    //print( "=========VV==========" )
    //print( "URL: \(URL) " )
    //print( "data: \(String(describing: data))" )
    //print( "auth: \(myUserIdForBulkSmsMessageSending)   \(myUserPasswordForBulkSmsMessageSending)")
    //print( "=====================" )
    swiftRequest.post(url: URL,
                      data: data,
                      auth: ["username" : myUserIdForBulkSmsMessageSending, "password" : myUserPasswordForBulkSmsMessageSending],
        callback: {err, response, body in
            if err == nil {
                print("Success: \(String(describing: response))")
                if let currentBody = body {

                    // SSTODO PENDING TO HANDLE SUCCESS OF TWILLO OR ERRORS HANDLING OF TWILLO.

                    //print( "=====================" )
                    //print( " currentBody:  \(currentBody) " )
                    //print( " currentBodyString: \(String(describing: currentBody)) ")
                    //print( "=========^^==========" )
                }
            } else {
                print("Error: \(String(describing: err))")
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 version:

```
func sendSMS()
{
    print("Starting...")
    let twilioSID = "ENRET YOUR SID"
    let twilioSecret = "YOUR TOKEN"
    //Note replace + = %2B , for To and From phone number
    let fromNumber = "%29999999"// actual number is +9999999
    let toNumber = "%29999999"// actual number is +9999999
    let message = "Your verification code is 2212 for signup with"

    // Build the request
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string:"https://\(twilioSID):\(twilioSecret)@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/\(twilioSID)/SMS/Messages")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = "From=\(fromNumber)&To=\(toNumber)&Body=\(message)".data(using: .utf8)

    // Build the completion block and send the request
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        print("Finished")
        if let data = data, let responseDetails = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
            // Success
            print("Response: \(responseDetails)")
        } else {
            // Failure
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }).resume()
}
```